# Consulta para retornar vários registros em Store Procedure

Tags: mysql

Não sei se é possível realizar este procedimento para que retorne vários registros.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de divulgação de jogo online em específico 'Mu Online'.

Porém me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Tenho 1 `store procedure`, e preciso que ela me retorne todas as linhas de registros armazenados na base relacionados a um usuário.

Tenho uma chamada da sp que me traz o registro de convite para o jogo online, dela eu garanto os `dados owner_id` = (Dono do jogo online) e `server_id`(id do servidor online).

jà tenho o seguinte código que traz pra mim .

```
$invitation_data =  $this->select('CALL
sp_call_select_server_invitations(:person_id, :owner_id, :server_id)',
$this->getParameters());
```

Após eu faço um select dos registros do usuário dono do jogo online, e também do servidor online e precisaria que pra cada uma dessas entidades me retorna-se um registro. Porem a `store procedure` está me retornando apenas o primeiro registro que ela encontra. Por estar aprendendo a me virar agora com procedimentos armazenados resolvi postar a minha dúvida aqui. Se é possível que a minha sp retorne vários registros, como faço isso?

Este é o código da `procedure`, está tudo funcionando corretamente sem nenhum erro, porém precisaria que me retornasse mais de um registro.

```
BEGIN
     SELECT `person_id` as owner_id , `server_id` as server FROM `server_invitations` WHERE ((`player_id` = person_id) and (`active` =
 1) and (`accept` = 0)); END
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado por editar, sou novato e desconheço a maioria das regras. vai me servir de exemplo, atualizando já resolvi o problema que criei, estava utilizando a função fetch ao invez de fetchAll.

Answer (score 0):

Atualizando já resolvi o problema, estava utilizando a função fetch ao invez de fetchAll, bastou mudar e o problema foi resolvido.

```
public function select($query, $parameters) {

    $this->setDatabase('dvmufree');

    $conn = $this->getConnection();         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($parameters); $i++) {            $stmt->bindParam("{$parameters[$i][0][0]}", $parameters[$i][1][0]);         }

    $stmt->execute();       return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```